# Testing a component with no logic

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Should you test components that have no logic? My component only renders jsx and some other components from a file above. Here's the example :

```
import React from 'react';
import SubscriptionForm from './SubscriptionForm';
import './style.scss';
import { FiPhone, FiMail } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { FaFacebook, FaTwitterSquare, FaLinkedin } from 'react-icons/fa';

export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <div className="footer-container">
      <div className="footer-container__contact">
        <h2>Contact us</h2>
        <p>
          <FiMail /> test@test.com
        </p>
        <p>
          <FiPhone /> +31 6 - 1222 - 123
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="footer-container__subscription-form">
        <h2>Subscribe and never miss a release</h2>
        <SubscriptionForm />
      </div>
      <div className="footer-container__social">
        <h2>Follow us</h2>
        <div className="footer-container__social-icons">
          <FaFacebook className="footer-container__social-icon" />
          <FaTwitterSquare className="footer-container__social-icon" />
          <FaLinkedin className="footer-container__social-icon" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Should you test such components. All i can test is if it renders , right ? I've heard about snapshot testing , but i'm not sure if this is a case where i should use it.

Comment: Snapshot testing is good for this case as it saves time on writing assertions.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that there is a right answer for that but think about the value of the test always from the user's point of view.

Are you planning to change this to support translations? so it would be a good test by snapshot or just checking the labels on the page.
Does the snapshot test make sense for your team? or they would just update when get some error?

But the most important from my point of view (and the user) would be the style, a CSS change would be able to break the style of this component so you could think to support visual tests focused only on the whole pages to cover those scenarios, it takes a real screenshot to compare the images.